# Is there anywhere to get US gps pipeline route data?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am looking for an open database or spreadsheet containing the gps coordinates of pipelines the possibly plot on Google Earth?

Answer (score 5):

You can find geospatial data about this on [Data.gov](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=%22gas%20pipeline%22) (this links to gas pipelines, but you can look for other types of pipelines). To find the geographic region you are looking for, you can draw a boundary box over the map in the upper left.

(Disclaimer: I am the Evangelist for Data.gov)

Answer (score 4):

[In this project](http://www.rrc.state.tx.us/data/online/gis/index.php) they use pipeline data. Maybe you can contact with them for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Open Street Map has some pipeline data in the us, i.e. http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1lo

Answer (score 2):

The best available source is the National Pipeline Mapping System, but it is far from an open source.

https://www.npms.phmsa.dot.gov/

The public map viewer is not in a database format, and restricts you to viewing one county at a time. You can get access to database and other geospatial formats outside of the public map viewer, but you must be a government official or pipeline contractor. If you fit into the latter category, the restrictions on the data you can receive are pretty strong. If you are a local government official, you can receive an unrestricted copy of the dataset for your county only (which means that you can have a local government official request that information and share it with you).

https://www.npms.phmsa.dot.gov/DataAccessPolicy/policy.htm